# GGTS Convert to Grails fails with NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: grails, ggts

I've imported a Grails project and am attempting to "convert it to grails". When I do this, I"m getting a NoClassDefFound on the apache commons logging package. Where do I add the jar for this? Is this in the IDE's class path, the Grails class path or the app's class path? It does not appear to be in grails-2.2.4/lib. That is the first place I'd expect it. This appears to use Ivy, so should that come as a dependency? Below is the error I'm seeing:

```
Loading Grails 2.2.4
| Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.<clinit>(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:136)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.getAvailableScripts(GrailsScriptRunner.java:813)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:423)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:417)
| Error     at org.grails.ide.api.impl.GrailsConnectorImpl.executeCommand(GrailsConnectorImpl.java:160)
| Error     at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.run(GrailsProcess.java:130)
| Error     at org.grails.ide.eclipse.longrunning.process.GrailsProcess.main(GrailsProcess.java:93)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)
| Error Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:175)
| Error     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:147)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsRootLoader.loadClass(GrailsRootLoader.java:52)
| Error     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
| Error     ... 13 more
```

Comment: I get the same error if I create a Grails project with File -> New -> Grails Project.

Answer (score 1):

Remove jdk1.8. I had both 1.7 and 1.8 jdks installed and 1.8 was my default runtime for osx. The project was specified as 1.7 but GGTS is looking at the default java runtime. After removing 1.8, it all works as expected.